# Make latexdiff mark differences in title

Tags: latexdiff

I am using latexdiff for showing the difference between two latex documents, but for some reason latexdiff is not displaying differences in the title of a document.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Please elaborate on what "title of the document" means. It it the argument to the command `\title`? Also, give your command-line call that initiates `latexdiff`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I always use `wdiff` to mark the changes in two revisions of the same document. I do not know the pros and cons compared with `latexdiff`, but it works fine for me. First, you have to [download](http://www.gnu.org/s/wdiff/) and install `wdiff`. I do not know for windows, but for mac or linux you have to do the usual `./configure` & `make` [combination](http://tldp.org/LDP/LG/current/smith.html). Now you compare the two latex files with

`./wdiff --start-delete='\sout{' --end-delete='}' --start-insert='\uline{' --end-insert='}' version1.tex version2.tex > diff.tex`

in the terminal. It puts the deleted parts between `\sout{` and `}`. It also puts the new parts between `\uline{` and `}`. You get a new file `diff.tex`. Open the file and make sure to use the `ulem` package. `wdiff` compares every word in the file, so if your were changing LaTeX macros and won't work well. It also does not like unmatched brackets, if you are changing e.g. only part of an equation.

My example output is

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Newer versions of `latexdiff` (1.0.3) do this out of the box

(Disclosure: I am the author of `latexdiff`)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)